# Windows 7: screen and keyboard frozen, computer still running in background

Tags: windows-7, freeze, truecrypt

I have this Windows 7 computer where, as I said, screen is frozen and computer is unresponsive. Usually I would just restart it. Thing is that I'm running Truecrypt's decryption process, so restarting the computer will likely ruin my installation.

I know the whole computer is not frozen because the disk has been working for hours (coherent with TC's decryption) and I can also access the network shares through my laptop. Also, the power scheme is working, as the screen turns off and I can turn it on again by touching any key.

It would be nice to recover control so that I can verify that the decryption process finished safely. I have tried the obvious things, alt-tab, alt-ctrl-del, and shift-ctrl-del.

Any suggestions?

Comment: plug in another USB keyboard?

Comment: Thanks. It was not the keyboard, it was either the window manager or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

So ctrl-alt-del does NOT give you back control, meaning bring up the big blue screen with the task manager option?

I don't think you have a lot of options then.  You could just wait it out of course and see if it comes back.  Or wait until the disk accesses stop and then restart it and see what happens.

You could try some kind of power management thing like a sleep or hibernate and see if this clears things up.  But that requires that you have a button, presumably the power button, pre-configured to invoke this.  So if its a laptop shut the screen.  Wait a while.  Open up.  Nope?  Is there a dedicated button for hibernate or sleep?  Did you pre-configure the power button to do something?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't try the sleep button. But after a few hours, consistent with Truecrypt's initial prediction, the hd activity waned, so I assumed that the decryption was finished. So I hard re-booted. Truecrypt showed a message I had never seen before that some errors had been corrected, and then it said the decryption was done. So that was it. It still was frustrating to have the operating system working but no giving me any control .